# How to pass a file in local edge node to a Java program triggered via Oozie

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I need to pass a file in local edge node to Oozie Java action. My intention is to use this as property file. I tried files tag but it seems like it is taking hdfs paths only.

Comment: Oozie does not know about Edge nodes. Oozie does not care about Edge nodes. Hadoop, as a whole, does not know/care about Edge nodes. Actually, an Edge node is **any machine** that can physically connect to the Hadoop services -- your PC, for instance... If you have a properties file, upload it to HDFS, and tell Oozie to download it at run-time with `<file>`

Comment: yes. i did the same. It was a property file and i passed it using <file>hdfs_path</file>. Then in my java class i used `ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
FileInputStream fileInputStream = loader.getResourceAsStream("application.properties");`.